# Flex 3 - Issues with textArea "editable" property

Tags: apache-flex, textarea

I'm having issues with the property "editable" of textArea control.

I have a component: OrderView.mxml and it's associated data class OrderViewData.as.

Orderview.mxml is inside a viewStack to enable navigation from a component to another. 
In this particular case, OrderView.mxml is called by another component: SearchResult.mxml. I can thus navigate from SearchResult.mxml to OrderView.mxml, and back to SearchResult.mxml...

OrderView.mxml has textArea and textInput control, that have to be editable or nonEditable depending on the property var isEditable:Boolean from OrderViewData.as.

When the application is launched, isEditable = true. So, all textInput and textArea controls are editable the first time the user gets to OrderView.mxml. When the user clicks on the button order from OrderView.mxml, isEditable = false. When the user goes back to SearchResult.mxml, isEditable = true (again) --> Until here, everything works fine.

The thing is: when the user goes back to OrderView.mxml for the second time (and beyond), even if the property isEditable = true, textArea controls are still non editable... But the textInput controls are editable!

Here is some code for your comprehension:
OrderView.mxml

```
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
    backgroundColor="#F3EDEC">

    <mx:TextArea 
        id="contentTA"
        text="{OrderViewData.instance.contentTA}"
        enabled="{OrderViewData.instance.isEnabled}" 
        width="100%" height="51" 
        maxChars="18" styleName="ORTextInput"
        focusIn="if(OrderViewData.instance.isEditable) contentTA.setSelection(0, contentTA.length)"
        editable="{OrderViewData.instance.isEditable}"/>

    <mx:TextInput id="contentTI" 
        text="{OrderViewData.instance.contentTI}"
        width="40" height="18" maxChars="4" 
        styleName="ORTextInput"
        change="contentTI_change()"
        focusIn="if(OrderViewData.instance.isEditable) contentTI.setSelection(0, contentTI.length)"
        editable="{OrderViewData.instance.isEditable}"/>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looks like anybody has more ideas...

I came up with a not really clean solution. But it works...

I used a init function in the show event of the component, where I create the control and add it to the proper parent. Thus, the mxml code written before has been deleted =)

This init function looks like this:

```
private function init():void
{
    // contentTA
    if(contentTA != null && parentBox.contains(contentTA))
        parentBox.removeChild(contentTA);

    contentTA = new TextArea;

    contentTA.text = OrderViewData.instance.contentTA;
    contentTA.enabled = OrderViewData.instance.isEnabled;
    contentTA.percentWidth = 100;
    contentTA.height = 51;
    contentTA.maxChars = 50;
    contentTA.styleName = "ORTextInput";
    contentTA.editable = OrderViewData.instance.isEditable;
    contentTA.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, focusIn);

    parentBox.addChild(contentTA);

    // same thing for all the other textAreas of my component       
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you make your isEditable variable [Bindable]?

Comment: Hi!
Yes, the  variable is Bindable. As I said, the textInput controls do take into account the modification of the variable isEditable.

I added an Alert on the textArea to show the value of isEditable and the property editable of the control. Even if "isEditable" is set to true, "editable" stays set to false...